# Homebrewインストール後 brew doctorででる警告メッセージについて

Tags: homebrew, cmake

HomebrewでMac(Sierra)に、PHP, Apache, MySQLをインストールしている途中ですが、何しろ、初心者ですので、ぐたいてきにわかりやすく教えて欲しいです。

まず、http://vdeep.net/intr-homebrew
を読んで観て
xCodeはすでにインストール済みでしたので

Homebrewをインストールしました。
(homebrew 1.2.1)

#### Q1)$ brew doctorを実行すると

つぎの警告メッセージができますが、これは無視してももんだいないのでしょうか。もしくは、問題があるとすれば、どのように解決するればよいのでか教えてください。
「Warning: Some frameworks can be picked up by CMake's build system and likely
cause the build to fail. To compile CMake, you may wish to move these
out of the way:
  /Library/Frameworks/libcurl.framework」

### #

Answer (score 1):

エラーではなく警告ですので、特に問題が起きなければ無視しても問題ありません。
ちなみに警告の意味は「CMakeというツールを使ってビルドするプログラムをインストールする場合、CMake側の問題で期待しているのとは違うライブラリが使われる（リンク）ことがあるので、そのような場合は一時的に問題のフレームワーク(/Library/Frameworks/libcurl.framework)を別のフォルダに移動してださい」です。
意味がわからなければ、問題になった時にまた聞くことをお勧めします。